# .Net core and IIS 10.0 gives HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, .net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-2.2

I know that this question is asked a lot. And I have checked all of the questions and all of the answers, but most of them are out of dated or not working.

I'm facing an issue when running my .Net core project, whenever I lunch the project, the error screen is displayed directly (Error image is attached with the description).

**.NET core version is 2.2, IIS is 10.0 and Visual Studion Community 2019**

Here's a snippet of my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".kmz" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz" />
   </staticContent>
  <handlers>
   <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false" />
  <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
   </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
   <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="31000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
 </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've tried the following steps:

1. Installed .net core hosting bundle
2. Removed the duplicate displaying in the error screen from `web.config`
3. Wasn't able to add the `IIS_USRS` to permissions in IIS because I didn't find such a user.
4. Removing the project and then cloning again from my git repository (the same error occured)

[image]

Comment: The error message looks just like you specify mimetype for .kml in both web.config and applicationhost.config. Have you checked that? You could compare the configuration in configuration manager. Besides, please enable failed request tracing, it will provide more details.

Comment: How do you enable failed request tracing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis